# Variable indexing in gekko

Tags: python, optimization, indexing, nonlinear-optimization, gekko

How can I index variables to solve a nonlinear optimization problem in python gekko package? For example, how can I write the objective function below into a single equation indexing the variable x?

[image: For example:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `m.Array()` function to create a variable (or parameter) array. The `np.prod()` and `m.sum()` functions are used to define the objective function `m.Maximize()` and the equation `m.Equation()`.

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
n = 5
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
x = m.Array(m.Var,n,value=1)
m.Maximize(np.prod([m.sqrt(xi) for xi in x]))
m.Equation(m.sum(x)==100)
m.solve(disp=False)
print(x)
```

Solution:

```
[[20.0] [20.0] [20.0] [20.0] [20.0]]
```

Comment: Dear John Hedengren, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept the answer if it is what you needed.